# What is the reason/story behind Lord Sri Venkateshwara called as Balaji?

Tags: history, name, venkateshwara

There are many names with which the Lord Venkateswara is called. Of course the sahasranama is devoted to Lord Vasudeva and all his avatars and the one in the question is definitely included.  Leaving that behind He is also called as Govinda, Thiruvenkatamudayan, Srinivasan etc and many solkas and archana mantras enumerate his names.  But none of these seems to have the name Balaji listed but still it is very popular especially with North Indians.

Usually every name will have some sort of anecdote however small or big it might be. What is such with the name Balaji?

Comment: There are two theories on why he's called Balaji: one that it's taken from Balaka, a name of Krishna conveying his youthful appearance, and the other that it's taken from Bala which is a name of Durga, from the days when people used to consider the statue to be Durga. You see, there was a time when there was a lot of confusion on the identity of the statue; various people thought it was Vishnu, Shiva, Kartikeya, Durga, and Buddha. This confusion was resolved by Ramanujacharya, who gave both arguments for why it must be Vishnu, and he demonstrated it was Vishnu using the locked-doors miracle.

Comment: By the way, this book says there's no record of the name Balaji before the 17th century: https://books.google.com/books?id=aKEcAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA117&img=1&pgis=1&dq="word+balaji"&sig=ACfU3U2D1XdUgGeaxW9AX2Y0Fk5ASac15A&edge=0

Comment: @Keshav What was Ramanuja's experiment of locked doors?

Comment: @Surya Because there was a controversy concerning who the statue depicted, there was a perpetual fight over what ornaments to put in the statue's hands, e.g. Kaumaras wanted to put a Vel in his lower hand. Now Ramanujacharya had first given detailed scriptural arguments showing that the statue is Vishnu, but the priests of other sects weren't willing to listen. So he proposed a test: put all the proposed ornaments in the Garbagraha and lock the doors overnight, and let the statue choose its ornaments.  In the morning, when the doors were unlocked, the statue was holding the Shankha and Chakra!

Comment: @Surya That settled the matter once and for all, and Tirupati has been a Vishnu temple ever since.  Sri Vaishnavas believe that what really happened is that Ramanujacharya, being an avataram of Adiseshan, took the form of a tiny snake and went through the crevice of the door and then put the Shankha and Chakra on the statue.  By the way, if you want to see Ramanujacharya's arguments for why it must be Vishnu, as well as the story of how he saved the temple, you can read the Venkatachala Itihasamala: https://archive.org/details/srivenkatachalai015452mbp

Comment: @Keshav Your first answer dazzled me and the second chagrined me. Why on earth should Ramanuja do that? Wasn't it he who set the condition that the doors should be locked? Isn't perumal capable enough to hold his own Ayudhas?

Comment: @Surya Well, Adiseshan is an incarnation of Vishnu, so either way Vishnu was the one who did it.  It's up to Vishnu how he chooses to carry out his miracles.  Perhaps he did not want to break the pose that he had assumed all the way back when he got married to Padmavathi, he may have wanted to remain permanently in that position for the duration of the Kali Yuga.  Ramanujacharya just wanted to show the other priests a miracle to convince them, it doesn't matter what the nature of the miracle was.

Comment: @Surya By the way, the reason the ornaments argument started is that the statue didn't have its original Shankha and Chakra.  In fact that was one of the arguments that people used against the statue being Vishnu: "If it's Vishnu then where are his Shankha and Chakra?" Ramanujacharya explained how the Puranas say that Venkateshwara donated his Shankha and Chakra to the king Thondaman when Thondaman was fighting his civil war, but his arguments fell on deaf ears.  In any case, the current Shankha and Chakra the statue is holding aren't the original divine Shankha and Chakra.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Chakra and Shanka are not original one? I asked you why His chakra is vertical rather than horizontal and you told me other reason? Anyways, how did Sri Vaishnavas know that Ramanujacharya put  weapons? I saw a video where Ramadeekshutulu Pantulu (main preist of TTD) explained statue as Vishnu by describing His chest and face. He says statue is extra terrestial and Ramana deekshutulu has PHD in microbiology. It was prophesied by VeeraBrahmam garu that temple of Tirupati will gain prominence over temples.

Comment: @AnilKumar Well, what I told you is that the vertical Sudarshana Chakra seems to be a universal feature of Vishnu statues, not just in Tirupati, so I speculated that maybe Vishnu holds his chakram vertically when it's not in use and then spins it on his finger only when he's about to launch it.  In any case, yeah, the current Shankha and Chakra are not the originals, they're just a little over a thousand years old.  Venkateshwara gave the originals to his devotee king Thondaman so that Thondaman could win his battle, and then it's not known what happened to them after that.

Comment: @AnilKumar I'm not sure how where the story Ramanujacharya turning into a snake comes from.  It's possible that Ramanujacharya told his disciples that he did that, but I think it's more likely that it's just speculation because Sri Vaishnavas consider Ramanujacharya an incarnation of Adiseshan and so they just assumed that he turned into a snake. And yeah, Ramanujacharya gives very detailed arguments, both based on the appearance of the statue and based on scriptural accounts of the story of Venkateshwara, for why the statue must be Vishnu.  I suggest you read the Venkatachala Itihasamala.

Comment: Just to add what is being said, just the presence of Sanka and Chakra alone does not stand as an identity of paramapursha Sri Vasudeva.  Many nithya soories do have this capability and in one explanation when Alwar saw the Lord he was convinced by seeing Sri Mahalakshmi (& Srivatsam) and confirmed that it is the Lord indeed. The explanator says that is the reason he says 'திரு கண்டேன்' (saw Sri Mahalakshmi) as the first word the moment he saw the Lord. Perhaps this is what that chief priest would have followed.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan The story of Ramanujacharya becoming a snake and putting the Shankha and Chakra is just a story added later. What actually happens is Ramanujacharya prays the Lord to chose his right form and prove to the world what he actually is. When they opened the doors the next morning, all the weapons and ornaments except the Shankha and Chakra fell down. Then Ramanujacharya put Shankha and Chakra according to Pancharatra Agama to the Lord and thus became acharya to the God. Venkateshwara ordered the Yadava king to chant the name of Ramanuja every time they take His name at Tirumala.

Comment: "Raamaanujaa divyaajnaam vardhatham abhivardhatham" this line is recited at every Venkateshwara temple along with other acharya taniyan.

Comment: It is Hathiram Bavaji who gave Lord Venkateshwara the name of Balaji. This is because Lord Venkateshwara appeared in front of him as a boy, so he called him as Balaji. If you have any doubt, see this movie https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Om_Namo_Venkatesaya  :)

Answer (score 8):

There is an interesting story behind the  how Lord Venkateshwara got that name. This is not because of the confusion of who the deity in Tirumala is.

Once upon a time, there was a controversy between various sects of our religion on who is the presiding deity of Tirumala. There were different theories that the deity in Tirumala is Shiva, Shakthi, Kartikeya, Srimannarayana. Many debates were held among those sectarians regarding this issue. But no one could prove their theory as correct.

But Bhagavad Ramanujacharya, founder of Visishtadvaita philosophy visited Tirumala and took part in the debate with other sectarians. He proved that the presiding deity is none other than Srimannarayana through debate and also an experiment called locked doors(see the comments thread). By that experiment, all were convinced that Venkateshwara is none other than Srimannarayana.

In His lifetime, Bhagavad Ramanujacharya visited Tirumala 3 times and organised the *puja vidhanam* to the Lord and made rules on how the Lord should be worshiped. He also appointed his disciples to carry on the tradition of worship to the lord.

**How did Lord Venkateshwara get the name Balaji?**

Bhagavad Ramanuja made the rules on how Venkateshwara should be worshiped and different sevas performed to the Lord like *Abhishekam* etc.,.

On a Friday(Ramanuja was the one who made the rule that *abhishekam* should be performed and it is followed till date) while *Abhishekam*(holy bath) was being performed to the lord with the Akasa Ganga waters,The white part of the tirunamam of Lord Venkateshwara got melted and only red part and white part under the eye brows of Venkateshwara was visible(Like the women of Sri Vaishnava tradition wear the namam). Looking at that scene, Sri Ramanujacharya got mesmerized by that beauty of the Lord and thought in his mind as follows:

> Oh Lord! How beautiful you are, How beautiful your face is. I am mesmerized by your beauty.  Once you took the incarnation of Mohini and mesmerized the worlds with your beauty. May be you are desiring to look like that again and make the people happy.

After this thought, the Lord conquered one of priests who were abhishekam said in a loudly voice as an approval. **Yes Ramanuja! I am desiring to look like that**. People who were sitting along with Ramanujacharya and watching the *abhishekam* were astonished by those words and didn't know the meaning of that. Later Sri Ramanujacharya explained. Thus Sri Ramanujacharya made a rule that the Lord should be decorated as [Mohini avatar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohini) wearing a saree on Monday, tuesday, wednesday. On Thursday, Lord should be decorated with different flowers and a namam made of jewels should be put. On Friday, saturday and sunday, He should be decorated with different jewels.

This rule was well performed till the early 18<sup>th</sup> century. In the 18 century, the Mahanths reigned over the temple administration of Tirumala. By that time, the facilities on the Seven hills were improved. The number of devotees visiting Tirumala from northern states of India has increased. People who have seen Lord Venkateshwara in saree were pleased and called Him **Balaji**. Bala means a beautiful woman in Hindi. Ji means the respect people give to the deities for example : Ganeshji, Shivji etc.,  . Thus the name of Balaji got popularised in the north India even though He has other names. This is the real reason behind the history of the name Balaji. But this tradition of decorating the Lord with saree is forgotten by present TTD board who are the administrators of the temple.

This story was [explained](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DdYZga2sZzI&list=PLF5292A308C50954F) by *HH Sri Sri Sri Tridandi Chinna Srimannarayana Ramanuja Jeeyar swami* as a part of explaining the history and importance of Tirumala.

Answer (score 0):

It is Hathiram Bavaji who gave Lord Venkateshwara the name of Balaji.

This is because Lord Venkateshwara appeared in front of him as a boy, so he called him as Balaji.

If you have any doubt, see this movie https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Om_Namo_Venkatesaya  :)

Hathiram Bavaji is also from North India who worshipped Lord Venkateshwara in Tirupati.

Comment: TV shows and movies are not considered as valid sources on the site. Add something more valid.

Comment: See this sentense "According to legend Hathiram named Lord Venkateswara as Balaji.[4] " from wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hathiram_Bhavaji